# Change size of image inside DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to build my own website as a portfolio website. I'm trying to add a image inside a div but when the image gets bigger the div also gets bigger. I just want the image to be a bit bigger but the div size to be the same. Down here you can find my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gckw3p9L/

The code I'm talking about is this one:

```
<div class="bar">
  <div class="barStyle">
    <p class="paragraphBar"><img src="images/icon2.png" width="20px" height="20px" alt"Projects">TEST TEST.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this will help you

```css
    .image-wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        height:150px;
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper" style="background-image: url('http://www.lorempixel.com/200/300')"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
display: table;
```

Will make the div the same size as the image. Though why don't you just use a background-image instead of a img if you allways want them to be the same size?

EDIT:
Div:

```
width: 20%;
max-width: 20%;
max-height: 200px;
height: 200px;
```

Comment: No, I want the image to be bigger, but the div needs to stay the same size (20% of the height)

Comment: That will make the div never to go over 20% width and 200px height ( just change the value to what you want )

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your div is fixed width and height

```
.barStyle{
    width:18px;
    height:18px;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

that make your image will a little bigger than your div